# MySQL Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error telling me that the value for column `sale_id` in table `funds` does not exist in table `sales`. This value is derived by getting the `LAST_INSERT_ID` of the previous sql query. Each query exists in different instances of different classes. The commented code is as follows:

```
//this method which runs the first query belongs to this class
class sales {

    public  $sale_id,
            $acc_id,
            $sale_amt,
            $sale_date;



    public function create() {
        $db = database::instance()->connect();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sales (sale_id,acc_id,sale_amt,sale_date) VALUES (DEFAULT, :acc_id, :sale_amt, :sale_date)";            
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);      
        $query->execute(array(
            ':acc_id' => $this->acc_id,
            ':sale_amt' => $this->sale_amt,
            ':sale_date' => $this->sale_date)
        );
        $perc = (Get('accounts','acc_perc','acc_id',$this->acc_id)); $perc = $perc[0];


        //create an instance of another class, "funds"
        $fund = new funds;
            $fund->acc_id = $this->acc_id;      
            $fund->fund_amt_total = $perc * $this->sale_amt;
            $fund->fund_date = $this->sale_date;


        //call a method of the class "funds"
        $fund->create();
    }           
}
```

The second class, which runs the second query

```
class funds {

    public  $fund_id,
            $acc_id,
            $sale_id,
            $fund_amt,
            $fund_date;

    public function create() {
        $db = database::instance()->connect();


        //sale_id is the value returned from LAST_INSERT_ID(), which is the sale_id from the preceding entry
        $sql = "INSERT INTO funds (sale_id,fund_id,acc_id,fund_amt,fund_date) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),DEFAULT,:acc_id,fund_amt,:fund_date)";

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);

        $query->execute(array(
            ':acc_id' => $this->acc_id,
            ':fund_amt' => $this->fund_amt_total,
            ':fund_date' => $this->fund_date)
        ); //error occurs on this line
    }
}
```

The first error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`coop1`.`funds`, CONSTRAINT `funds_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `sales` (`sale_id`))' in C:\wamp\www\coop1\1\classes.php on line 62
```

Second error code

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`coop1`.`funds`, CONSTRAINT `funds_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `sales` (`sale_id`)) in C:\wamp\www\coop1\1\classes.php on line 62
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` is only valid within the same database connection. You call `database::instance()->connect()` in each class, I'm guessing you're getting a new connection each time, so it doesn't have the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` from the previous `INSERT`.

It also seems like a bad design to have `funds::create()` depend on the fact that the last query was from `sales::create()`.

You should have `sales::create()` return the ID of the row it added, and pass this as an argument to `funds::create()`

Comment: I did exactly that and it worked! helped me over a snag and taught me better design